# Edit a file in an ElasticBeanStalk Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, laravel-5.4

I want to edit a file I uploaded and deployed to `ELasticBeanStalk`, I don't want to always zip and deploy whenever I am adding or removing features from my `Laravel` app. Another reason I don't to always deploy is the fact that my users can upload images for their profiles, whenever I upload and deploy a new version of my app, they lose these images stored in the `Storage` folder.

**So far:**

I have tried using `WinScp` to login into the `ElasticBeanStalk` instance of my `Laravel` app but could not find any file in the root folder.

I will appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: You should be developing new features in your local development environment, not directly on the production server, and you should be storing user-uploaded content in a persistent storage location such as EBS, S3 or RDS.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I ended up using S3 for my app.